# Excel VSTO does not fire Add comment

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

In one `Excel Add-in` project for `Excel 2013` I need to check the event for the `Adding, Modifying, Deleting` Comments in Cells. I am trying to get this info from `SheetSelectionChange` event and `SheetChange` events. However, the actuall event is not fired, after I add new comment. Could someone point to the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *"**check the event** for the Adding, Modifying, Deleting comments"*? What is your current code for the `SheetSelectionChange`?

Comment: When I add the Comment to the Range the SheetSelectionChange event is not firing. I need to get that event

Comment: what is your current SheetSelectionchange? How are you checking if a comment has been added?

Comment: Yes, I certainly check that. So, in order to replicate this issue you can do the folowing. In Active Cell add a comment (right click Add comment), you will notice that SheetSelectionChange wont be fired. I exlicitly set breakpoing in the begining of the SheetSelectionChange.

Comment: it will not fire because the .addComent, .edit and .remove are macros themselfs so there is no way to interact with it. You may check if the comment has been added using the Worksheet_Change event but it may be just an overkill to check if a comment has been added everytime a sheet recalculates.. Maybe tell us what you are doing there might be an alternative

Comment: I am already experimenting with Worksheet_Change but they work only if I leave the Cell. However, while I am inside the cell and do Add, Modify, Delete comments non of those events fire.

Comment: because there are no events that support comments.

Comment: Ok, thats great to know...even if it is negative

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on copy/paste event.

One possible solution is overwrite the micro, you can call a c# method from micro before applying the comment.

I succeeded on this but it is tricky.

Comment: Correct, but in my opinion this solution defeats the VSTO purpose:)